# Android LinearLayout is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am working on an android application.

I have an issue, my `LinearLayout` widget is not visible on the screen.

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        // Other widgets

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        // Other widgets

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        // Other widgets
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In that case `linear_layout_row3` is not visible on the screen.

If I move it up it will be showed, however the layout moved below wouldn't be visible.

I don't understand the problem, could you help to find it?

Answer (score 2):

Change   `android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row_container`

```
android:weightSum="2"
```

to

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

      // Other widgets

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

      // Other widgets

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

      // Other widgets
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```